# Фильтрация элементов массива по указанному значению

Tags: javascript

Добрый день. Необходимо написать функцию, которая фильтрует студентов по группе. Функция должна возвращать только тех студентов, что учатся в указанной группе.

Не могу понять, что именно тут использовать. Заранее спасибо.

Исходный код:

```
var groupmates = [
 {
 "name": "Andrey",
 "group": "912-2",
 "age": 19,
 "marks": [4, 3, 5, 5, 4]
 },
 {
 "name": "Artem",
 "group": "912-1",
 "age": 18,
 "marks": [3, 2, 3, 4, 3]
 },
 {
 "name": "Lisa",
 "group": "912-2",
 "age": 19,
 "marks": [3, 5, 4, 3, 5]
 },
 {
 "name": "Irina",
 "group": "912-1",
 "age": 18,
 "marks": [5, 5, 5, 4, 5]
 }
];
console.log(groupmates);

var rpad = function(str, length) {
// js не поддерживает добавление нужного количества символов
// справа от строки то есть аналога ljust из языка Python здесь нет
str = str.toString(); // преобразование в строку
while (str.length < length)
str = str + ' '; // добавление пробела в конец строки
return str; // когда все пробелы добавлены, возвратить строку
};
var printStudents = function(students){
 console.log(
 rpad("Name", 15),
 rpad("Group", 8),
 rpad("Age", 8),
 rpad("Marks", 20)
 );
 // был выведен заголовок таблицы
 for (var i = 0; i<=students.length-1; i++){
 // в цикле выводится каждый экземпляр студента
 console.log(
 rpad(students[i]['name'], 15),
 rpad(students[i]['group'], 8),
 rpad(students[i]['age'], 8),
 rpad(students[i]['marks'], 20)
 );
}
 console.log('\n'); // добавляется пустая строка в конце вывода
};
printStudents(groupmates);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте [`Array.prototype.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter):

```
// Функция-фильтр
var filterStudents = function (students, group) {
    return students.filter(function(student) {
        return (student.group == group);
    });
};

// Использование
var groupmates = [/* ... */];
console.dir(filterStudents(groupmates, '912-1'));
```

А вот и [рабочий пример](https://jsfiddle.net/qgsnhm5p/) на JSFiddle.

Comment: если мне нужно именно ввести номер группы, а не сразу его называть, нужно использовать input?

Comment: Если речь о браузере, то `prompt`. Ну и это не имеет отношения к собственно _фильтрации_ ;)

Comment: Все равно почему-то не выводит. Была попытка заменить console.dir на console.log -- ничего(

Comment: @R.Lin врете вы всё, код работает так, как и должен. Пруф: https://jsfiddle.net/qgsnhm5p/

Comment: ааа, все, нашла ошибку в своем коде)
спасибо большое)

Answer (score 0):

```js
let groupmates = [
 {
 "name": "Andrey",
 "group": "912-2",
 "age": 19,
 "marks": [4, 3, 5, 5, 4]
 },
 {
 "name": "Artem",
 "group": "912-1",
 "age": 18,
 "marks": [3, 2, 3, 4, 3]
 },
 {
 "name": "Lisa",
 "group": "912-2",
 "age": 19,
 "marks": [3, 5, 4, 3, 5]
 },
 {
 "name": "Irina",
 "group": "912-1",
 "age": 18,
 "marks": [5, 5, 5, 4, 5]
 }
],
    select = document.querySelector('#select'),
    log = document.querySelector('#log');


// Заполняем select уникальными группами
let tmp = new Set(), res = '';
groupmates.forEach(e => tmp.add(e.group));
select.innerHTML = '<option>' + Array.from(tmp).join('</option><option>') + '</optino>';



select.addEventListener('change', function(e){
  let option = this.selectedOptions[0];
  
  render(filter(option.innerHTML));
});

// Фильтруем группы
function filter(groupId){
  return groupmates.filter(g => g.group === groupId);
}

function render(data){
  let res = '';
  
  data.forEach(s => res += `Имя: ${s.name}<br />Возраст: ${s.age}<br />Отметки: ${s.marks.join`, `}<br /><br />`);
  
  log.innerHTML = res;
}
```

```html
<select id='select'></select><br />
<div id='log'></div>
```

Comment: Когда пытаюсь выводить в консоли, выдает ошибку. Подскажите, пожалуйста, что сделать.

Comment: @R.Lin, режим телепата только для купивших подписку. Остальным нужно сообщить хотя бы что за текст ошибки.